# Checkout original during git patch add

Tags: git

Is there any way to add an option to `git add --patch` that would allow me to delete hunks that I don't like, rather than simply leaving them unstaged?

For some context, I'm using Xcode to work with iOS, and one of the irritating things about the IDE is that when you edit storyboards, a lot of miscellaneous changes are made that aren't strictly necessary and tend to clutter code reviews. Our practice to deal with this is to use `add --patch` in order to select the important changes, and then `checkout -- <storyboard>` to clean up what's left. It would be more convenient if in addition to the `--patch` options of `add` `ignore` `split` and `search`, we had `checkout` or `remove` that would remove that change from the working directory.

Comment: You can `git reset --patch` to interactively modify the index version of the file back towards the `HEAD` version. I always find, however, that at the point at which `add --patch` and/or `reset --patch` start getting this complicated, it's far better to `mv file.ext file.ext.combined` and then `git checkout HEAD file.ext; mv file.ext file.ext.orig` and build up a new `file.ext` using my editor and the two saved variants.

Comment: (That's not quite the same as what you asked for, but again, I find that what you're asking for is unmanageable in an interactive Git command. I'd rather just edit!)

Comment: @torek Unmanageable from a practical or conceptual standpoint?

Comment: Practical (theoretically, if I had infinite mental bandwidth, it would be fine conceptually :-) ).